# How to fix 'Cannot find module './access-error.js' error when i'm going to install npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

I develop node api. When i changed project direction and call `npm install` then show me

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './access-error.js'
```

please help me for install npm in direction project.

Comment: same issue. Tried to install latest but it cannot get past that error for some reason.

Comment: I was forced delete node and npm from /local/ then install again and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force delete node and npm from your mac，use this command:

```
> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}
```

And then reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have duplicated entries to node in your system path.
Removing extra "/Users/rafal/.node/bin" in system PATH helped me in this problem.